# Error when sending emails with asp.net ('At least one of the fields From or To are required')

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to send emails using asp.net. Here's what i've got so far:

```
objEmail = New Email

                With objEmail
                    If (IsDBNull(rsConfigEmail.Fields("smtp").Value)) Then
                        Dim sSmtp As String = CarregarSMTP()

                        If (sSmtp = "") Then
                            'Throw New Exception("Não existem SMTPs cadastrados.")
                            MsgBox.Disparar("Erro ao enviar email. SMTP não cadastrado.")
                            Exit Sub
                        End If

                        .SMTP = sSmtp
                    Else
                        .SMTP = rsConfigEmail.Fields("smtp").Value
                    End If
                    .Remetente = Trim(rsConfigEmail.Fields("Remetente").Value)
                    .Titulo = Trim(rsConfigEmail.Fields("assunto").Value)
                    .Destinatario = sEmail

                    corpoEmail = rsConfigEmail.Fields("Mensagem").Value.ToString()

                    corpoEmail = corpoEmail.Replace("<guia>", sGuia)
                    corpoEmail = corpoEmail.Replace("<origem>", dplOrgao.SelectedItem.Text)
                    corpoEmail = corpoEmail.Replace("<destino>", Trim(rsDadosEmail.Fields("sigla").Value.ToString()) + " - " + Trim(rsDadosEmail.Fields("descricao").Value.ToString()))

                    Dim tabela As String = ""
                    tabela += "<table width='100%'><tr><td>Número Processo</td><td>Número Documento Origem</td><td>Assunto</td><td>Complemento</td><td>Interessado</td><td>Parecer</td></tr>"
                    Do While Not rsConfirmados.EOF
                        tabela += "<tr><td>" + rsConfirmados.Fields(0).Value.ToString() + "</td><td>" + rsConfirmados.Fields(1).Value.ToString() + "</td><td>" + rsConfirmados.Fields(2).Value.ToString() + "</td><td>" + rsConfirmados(3).Value.ToString() + "</td><td>" + rsConfirmados.Fields(4).Value.ToString() + "</td><td>" + rsConfirmados.Fields(5).Value.ToString() + "</td></tr>"
                        rsConfirmados.MoveNext()
                    Loop
                    tabela += "</table>"

                    corpoEmail = corpoEmail.Replace("<corpo>", tabela)
                    corpoEmail = corpoEmail.Replace("<total>", rsConfirmados.RecordCount.ToString())

                    .Mensagem = corpoEmail
                    .Enviar()


                End With
```

When the 'Enviar' method is called (Send()), an exception is thrown saying that At least one of the fields 'from' or 'to' is required. But i'm setting values to these properties when i do this:

```
.Remetente = Trim(rsConfigEmail.Fields("Remetente").Value)
 .Destinatario = sEmail
```

From and To fields respectively. Could it be something wrong with my smtp address?

Here's the Enviar() method in my Email class:

```
Public Sub Enviar()
            Dim mail As MailMessage
            Dim TemDestinatario As Boolean

            Try

                If sSMTP.Trim <> "" Then
                    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = sSMTP
                Else
                    Throw New Exception("Falta o SMTP.")
                End If

                mail = New MailMessage

                If sRemetente <> "" Then
                    mail.From = sRemetente
                Else
                    Throw New Exception("Falta o Remetente.")
                End If

                TemDestinatario = False
                If sDestinatario <> "" Then
                    mail.To = sDestinatario
                    TemDestinatario = True
                End If
                If sDestinatarioCCO <> "" Then
                    mail.Bcc = sDestinatarioCCO
                    TemDestinatario = True
                End If
                If Not TemDestinatario Then
                    Throw New Exception("Falta o Destino.")
                End If

                mail.Subject = sTitulo
                mail.Body = sTexto
                mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text

                If Not vetAnexo Is Nothing AndAlso UBound(vetAnexo) > 0 Then
                    Dim intContador As Integer
                    For intContador = 0 To UBound(vetAnexo) - 1
                        mail.Attachments.Add(New MailAttachment(vetAnexo(intContador)))
                    Next
                End If

                'se houver algum problema no envio, tenta outros SMTPs
                Try
                    SmtpMail.Send(mail)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Dim cSig As Object
                    Dim rsSmtp As ADODB.Recordset

                    cSig = CreateObject("prSIG.cSMTP")

                    rsSmtp = cSig.ConsultarSMTP()

                    If (rsSmtp.RecordCount > 0) Then
                        Dim bEnviado As Boolean

                        'pega todos menos o que ja tentou, e ordena pela 'ordem'
                        rsSmtp.Filter = "smtp <> '" + SmtpMail.SmtpServer + "'"
                        rsSmtp.Sort = "ordem"

                        rsSmtp.MoveFirst()

                        Do While Not rsSmtp.EOF And Not bEnviado
                            Try
                                SmtpMail.SmtpServer = rsSmtp.Fields("smtp").Value
                                SmtpMail.Send(mail)
                                bEnviado = True
                            Catch
                            End Try

                            rsSmtp.MoveNext()
                        Loop

                        If (Not bEnviado) Then
                            Throw ex
                        End If
                    Else
                        Throw ex
                    End If

                End Try

            Catch ex As Exception
                If ex.Message = "Could not access 'CDO.Message' object." Then
                    Throw New Exception("Falha ao acessar o SMTP (" + sSMTP + ").")
                Else
                    Throw ex
                End If
            Finally
                mail = Nothing
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps show the code in the class 'Email'?

Comment: I've added the enviar method.

Comment: I've changed my From value and now i'm getting this error: The transport failed to connect to the server.  

I've tried with both my smtp adresses...could it be none of them are working?

Comment: Check out this checklist for reviewing of the "The transport failed to connect to the server" error      http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/4.3.9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Both of my SMTP adresses were not working. Had to ask for another STMP address. Now it works.